# Using noreply@domail.com instead of domain in PHPmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I want to send an email notification to all users who did not login to my website for continuous 10days. I have achieved the same as well, but I don't want to send the company name as a domain. Instead I am trying to change from address to be "noreply@domain.com".

```
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->MsgHTML($message);
$mail->SetFrom("support@domain.com", 'noreply@domain.com');
$mail->addReplyTo('support@domain.com', 'noreply@domain.com');
```

It worked, but while viewing in Gmail, my domain name was still visible like

noreply@domain.com <support@domain.com>.

Is it possible to hide or rename the domain email to be noreply@domain.com?

Comment: Who is your hosting provider?

Comment: It is hostgator.

Comment: Yeah you should change the STMP setting that is $mail variable.

Answer (score 2):

The second param on the `setFrom` and `addReplyTo` are the friendly names.

Documentation: https://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html#method_setFrom

```php
$mail->SetFrom('noreply@domain.com', 'Your Name');
$mail->addReplyTo('real-email-who-gets-replies@domain.com', 'Your Name');
```

A word of caution though is that your domain will need to have the proper e-mail configurations in place for the sender. Meaning that `noreply@domain.com` needs to actually exist. Most hosting providers can configure this for you. This is to reduce the chances of your domain seeming like SPAM and be blocked.

Comment: I have created a noreply@domain.com, but still the mails are not getting triggered when I use that mail. Any idea/suggestion?